# MySQL Query: Select most-recent items with a twist

Tags: sql, mysql

Sorry the title isn't more help. I have a database of media-file URLs that came from two sources:

(1) RSS feeds and (2) manual entries.

I want to find the ten most-recently added URLs, but a maximum of one from any feed. To simplify, table '`urls`' has columns `'url, feed_id, timestamp'`.

`feed_id=''` for any URL that was entered manually.

How would I write the query? Remember, I want the ten most-recent urls, but only one from any single `feed_id`.

Comment: are feed id's common between both tables?

Comment: only 1 table, 2 sources.

Comment: Assuming you want multiple manually entered items with 1 per feed id

Comment: Possible dup of [Selecting values grouped to a specific identifer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/118443/90527).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming feed_id = 0 is the manually entered stuff this does the trick:

```
select p.* from programs p
left join 
(
    select max(id) id1 from programs
    where feed_id <> 0
    group by feed_id
    order by max(id) desc
    limit 10
) t on id1 = id
where id1 is not null or feed_id = 0 
order by id desc
limit 10;
```

It works cause the id column is constantly increasing, its also pretty speedy. t is a table alias.

This was my original answer:

```
(
select 
    feed_id, url, dt 
    from feeds  
    where feed_id = ''
    order by dt desc 
    limit 10
)
union
(

select feed_id, min(url), max(dt) 
        from feeds
        where feed_id <> '' 
        group by feed_id
        order by dt desc    
        limit 10
)
order by dt desc
limit 10
```

Comment: in that case you can do something like where id in (select max(id) from table where feed_id <> '' group by feed_id) can you post example sql definitions with expected results?

Comment: why min(url)? supposing the url is different for each item, how do you know this url will be the one matching the most recent date?

Comment: this unions the last 10 entries, regardless of dupe feed with the last 10 by feed_id, which does nothing to give your desired results.  what does "min(url)" accomplish.  i do not think this will work.

Comment: min(url) is kind of tricky, it ensures that if we have 2 items with the same date we break the tie by sorting by url, its kind of rare and you can break the ties using max(id) as well

Comment: I think the subselect in the latest version may be a bit slow with 100,000+ feed_id's. Can it have a LIMIT, too? And what's the 'p' in the first FROM?

Comment: Let me know how this latest edit goes, it should be a bit faster, you can not use limits in subqueries in mysql

Comment: Nope. Latest version returns ten rows from one feed.

Comment: Sorry Doug, give the latest iteration a shot, i found the bug.

Comment: Yup, that does it. Seems reasonably fast, too. Thanks for the help. And to Stack Overflow for an awesome system.

Comment: To see the results, visit the new site, still early in development: spokenword.org. This SQL drives 'Recently Added Programs..." on the home page. Ugly for now (no CSS, etc.) but it works.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this table

```
  CREATE TABLE feed (
  feed varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  add_date datetime NOT NULL,
  info varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (feed,add_date);
```

**this query should do what you want**.  The inner query selects the last entry by feed and picks the 10 most recent, and then the outer query returns the original records for those entries.

```
  select f2.*
  from (select feed, max(add_date) max_date
          from feed f1
         group by feed
         order by add_date desc
         limit 10) f1
  left join feed f2 on f1.feed=f2.feed and f1.max_date=f2.add_date;
```

Comment: This is a good answer, and more of a general solution than the accepted answer which relies on having an auto-increment id.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the (abbreviated) table:

```
CREATE TABLE programs (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  feed_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And here's my query based on sambo99's concept:

```
(SELECT feed_id,id,timestamp 
    FROM programs WHERE feed_id='' 
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION
    (SELECT feed_id,min(id),max(timestamp) 
    FROM programs WHERE feed_id<>'' GROUP BY feed_id 
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Seems to work. More testing needed, but at least I understand it. (A good thing!). What's the enhancement using the 'id' column?

Comment: I expanded my answer to cover that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html). Something like this should work:

```
    (SELECT 
        url, feed_id, timestamp 
    FROM rss_items  
    GROUP BY feed_id 
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
    LIMIT 10)
UNION
    (SELECT 
        url, feed_id, timestamp 
    FROM manual_items  
    GROUP BY feed_id 
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
    LIMIT 10)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: you can't select url, feed_id, timestamp if you group by feed_id, you must use some aggregate function around whatever you do not group by (i.e. url and timestamp)

Comment: That's correct. The second SELECT returns at most one row since in the case of the manual feed, the feed_id is always ''. And to be clear, there's just one table.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have the greatest support for this type of query.

You can do it using a combination of "GROUP-BY" and "HAVING" clauses, but you'll scan the whole table, which can get costly.

There is a more efficient solution published here, assuming you have an index on group ids:
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1390#104

(Basically, create a temp table, insert into it top K for every group, select from the table, drop the table. This way you get the benefit of the early termination from the LIMIT clause).

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to group by the field that you want to be distinct?

SELECT url, feedid FROM urls GROUP BY feedid ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10;

Comment: assuming that I'm right in that there's only 1 table, I think this is a workable solution.

Comment: I tried something like that, but it only returns a max of one url that doesn't have a feed.